# Inserting Headers into a Data URI?

Tags: javascript, download

I'm trying to dynamically create data in JavaScript that downloads with a .csv extension, but am unable to associate a filename with the download.  Here's a code snippet:

```
var data = '1,2,3';
window.location = 
    "data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8;content-disposition:attachment;filename=export.csv," 
    + encodeURIComponent(data);
```

This downloads, but the file name is generic, without a .csv extension.

I can do this server-side, with the following PHP code:

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: text/csv');
   header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv');
   echo "1,2,3";
?>
```

Additionally, if my back is to the wall, I can modify my Javascript to send an Ajax out to the server and get this in return, but I'd prefer a pure Javascript solution.  Is there a browser-independent, Flash-free way of doing this?

***EDIT***

Someone pointed out this question as a possible duplicate.  I did goo-diligence and checked previous SO articles.  I am still asking this because some time has passed since those questions, so I am hoping:

1. Browser features may have changed favorably.
2. Older browsers are less of a constraint, so certain solutions may be more viable now than when the previous questions were asked.

Additionally, if it makes the question more palpatable, I'm specifically asking about inserting a type of content header into a data URI (as per the subject), which is a twist on the other questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922306/setting-filename-using-encodeuricomponent-to-let-user-download-data-file

Comment: @Chevi I know it's a duplicate, but since new extensions get added to browsers, I hoped something new came up in the meanwhile, hence my question.  Reverse case in point: the opposite seems to have happened.  The Filesystem API which was given as an answer does not work (I assume support was pulled or it was highly questionable to begin with).