# FileReader, crash in Chrome

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am trying to implement a file upload with dnd and FileReader for image preview.
It works quite good and also if i upload multiple files at ones.
But when i upload a second time images > ~1,6MB it crashes in chrome (firefox runs fine).
probably a bug in chrome but maybe anyone knows how to solve this?
Here an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/PTssx/7/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of MBs large Data URIs, you could also make use of `requestFileSystem`, to virtually store a copy of the file on the client's computer (in a location directly accessible by JavaScript). You then only have a file path which references to the actual contents (so this isn't a path to the original location; it starts with `filesystem:`).

Then again this is not supported by all browsers, but since you're already using `FileReader` I don't think this is much of an issue.

I altered a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160720/create-a-file-using-javascript-in-chrome-on-client-side/7160827#7160827) of mine to make it fit in your code: http://jsfiddle.net/PTssx/10/.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('test.png', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) { // create file
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            var builder = new BlobBuilder();
            builder.append(reader.result); // set file contents
            var blob = builder.getBlob();

            fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
                img.src = fileEntry.toURL(); // set img src to the file
            };

            fileWriter.write(blob);
        }, function() {});
    }, function() {});
}, function() {});

$('#items').append(img);
```

You then have to read the file as an `ArrayBuffer` instead of a Data URI:

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
```

`reader.result` will then be an `ArrayBuffer`.

**Note:** For now, in Chrome this technology has been implemented as `webkitRequestfileSystem` and `WebKitBlobBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid FileReader and FileSystem if i where you.
You can preview the image with just `img.src = URL.createObjectURL(File)`