# Writing to a text file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, io

I want to write to a text file using javascript. I know that it is possible but there are some problems.

I am running a javascript program that calculates the location of an object (its latitude & longitude) which changes every 5 seconds; i want to write this information to a text file. The javascript program will soon run on a server and I'll use the information written to the text file to communicate with an Android app on my phone.

So, my question really is:

1. How can it be done properly? 

   I know that there may be some permission issues but considering it won't be online and available to others will it be a problem and, if it is, should I go with PHP to do what I want? I know ASP is more Microsoft orientated and I work with a Mac so PHP would be the preference here.
2. When writing a file, is it possible to write to an existing file or does the process simply destroy and recreate the same file?

Comment: So... node.js? Otherwise, JavaScript doesn't really run on the server.

Comment: javascript on the client side (browser) or server side (e.g. with node.js)?

Comment: I think you might want to clarify your question. If the JavaScript programme is running *on the server* then you'll need to be running a JS engine there (probably Node), which would remove the need for a second server side language (such as PHP or one that is ASP compatible)

Comment: You should specify in which environment your JS is running. Browsers or server-side JS environments like node.js

Comment: If it isn't "online" then where is it? Are you planning a server-client app with both server and client running on a local network? Or is the entire thing running on the phone? (In which case, why is there a server involved?)

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160720/create-a-file-using-javascript-in-chrome-on-client-side

Comment: Ok allow me to clarify - my knowledge of javascript is limited therefore I don't know how it worked. The app i am creating will make contact with the server therefore it has to be online but what I meant was I will be the only one accessing it - no one else. The javascript program I have does some complex math which would be too bulky to run on the phone therefore it runs on the server and writes the values from the code to a text file on the server. The phone contacts the server to get this text file. So it will be running on a server side environment. Is this clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use PHP

http://www.php.net/

This has a good code example:

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php

Also, you can make the request using jQuery's AJAX function, this will allow to effectively run this code from javascript:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'm of the opinion that the question is too unclear to say if PHP might be appropriate or not … but even if it wasn't, this answer ignores most of the specific queries in it.

Comment: Duly noted, I added some further information, hopefully this will help

Answer (score 2):

Using the latest HTML5 Javascript, you can use the FileSystem APIs to read/write/append to text files. This is a good tutorial here : [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Comment: There's been no mention of HTML being involved. The question talks about a server and an Android application.