# How to save XML response locally with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm making an AJAX request. The returned `response` is a XML.

How can I let the user save the `response` as a XML file locally on `success` ?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(myJson),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: format,
    success: function(response)
    {
        console.log("Exported JSON: " + JSON.stringify(myJson));
        console.log(response);
        jQuery.parseXML(response);
    },
    error: function()
    {
        console.log(arguments);
        alert("Export process failed.");
    }
});
```

The `format` in this case is `xml`.

Comment: what do you mean by 'locally'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [create a file using javascript in chrome on client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160720/create-a-file-using-javascript-in-chrome-on-client-side)

Comment: like a window pop-up opens letting the user save the output as myFile.xml on their local hdd.

Comment: since you are not creating the xml file dynamically, I would rather use a `link` to that page and maybe open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a data URI will get you part way there.

```
window.open("data:text/xml;base64," + window.btoa(xmlString));
```

Using "application/octet-stream" instead of "text/xml" will even force a download prompt in FF and Chrome.

Unfortunately data URIs have size limits and there's probably a more clever approach using content editable and the exec 'save' or 'saveas' command.

Answer (score 1):

On success, render the response XML in a textarea or just a div and have the user copy+paste the results into a text editor. They can then save the file from the editor.

or

Instead of emitting the xml directly, provide a link to it instead.