# Client Javascript to download HTML and save to file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, download

I would like to see whether what I'm proposing sounds feasible. I'm not very up to date with javascript, but I think what I want to do is reasonable.

I've created a Chrome Extension, which is a Page Action that appears on sites with certain characteristics. What I would like to do is have an option in my `popup.html` that, when selected, will write the fully loaded DOM into a text file on the disk.

I've scoured and searched around, but I can't seem to find any clear examples of this functionality. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160720/create-a-file-using-javascript-in-chrome-on-client-side) helped me confirm that javascript will be able to help me capture the `.html`, but I'm not sure if I can trigger it from my extension's `popup.html`.

So, my question: Is it possible to download a page's html and write the file to the disk from a Chrome Extension?

As a follow up: Is it possible to execute a `.exe` file from a Chrome Extension? In other words, I would like to write the `.html` to the disk and then trigger a `.exe` file to do something to that file.

I'm going to attempt to do this in some fashion or another, but I would sincerely appreciate any pointers or help in the correct direction.

Comment: https://github.com/rndme/download you can open an exe by opening a specific mime type, choose "open" when prompted, browsing to the exe, and remembering the preference.

Comment: @dandavis Woo! Awesome. `download(document.documentElement.innerHTML, "download.html", "text/html")` and my problems are solved. Thanks!

Comment: glad my lib helped you out.

Comment: @dandavis It *really* did! Thanks again man!