# Create file using Java script/jq and save it in user pc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-filesystem

I wanna do some thing like this:
1 - user insert a name
2 - after that i create a file white the user inserted name, and save file in user drive, like c drive.
i need to do this using java script, but i have no idea about it, i saw some example about filesystem in Html5, but this approach, at the final, make u download the file, but i want to save this in a specified place by my self.
can u give me some guide or some document about this filed?
foe example i try this:
http://www.noupe.com/design/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit.html
but because i can't understood it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/  like this way..

Comment: You should check out this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160720/create-a-file-using-javascript-in-chrome-on-client-side

Comment: Don't think you can directly write to a folder on the user's computer. You can only prompt the browser to download a file which will go into the downloads folder 99% of the time.

Comment: tnk u both, but this links crest/talk about how to crate file and give it to user, i want crest file in a specified place, whit out make user download any thing, if I want say it in simple way, my user press some button and a file will be create in(for example) :  C:\mytemp\a.txt @user3588674 @/mubashir-abbas

Comment: @123 what if there is no `C:`? What if someone decides to create a 100GB file in your `C:`?

Comment: @php_nub_qq it's just a test, and i will use this app for trusted pc.

Comment: @123 it doesn't matter what you're going to use it for, if you can use it others can use it.

Comment: @php_nub_qq i guess i gone have some hard talk white my professor.

Comment: using a downloader script like  https://github.com/rndme/download , `download("hello world", "hello.txt");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, OK OK, tnk every body who came here and put there time to answer my question.
finally after a week, yesterday, i went to have some talk with my professor, and he smiled at me, and say u can't find it, bcz js don't have this access and i just need to see my student research about some thing, some thing with false answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a user's file system. The best you can do is use localStorage for normal browsers or cookies.

Comment: u know, in my own, i accepted ur words and i believe them, but i was talking to my proff and he mentioned this, and told me u can create a file like this, and in this way, but he simply don't explain it.

Comment: @123 No, you can't. If you could then the web would be a complete anarchy (not that it kind of isn't already).

Comment: you can download files from JS, you just can't specify the folder they are created in.

Comment: @dandavis yes, js let u create a temp file and give it to user, and then user must download the file.

Comment: perhaps your prog was meaning cookies? just a thought.  Thank goodness JS cannot just write files to our system willy-nilly.

Comment: @JonHolland no, no it's just a challenge between me and my professor :))

Comment: Local storage then perhaps?  [w3schools html 5 web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).  Although that is  not really a file that the user can then open.  Is your prof just trying to get rid of you for a couple of hours :) ?   Just seen php_nub_qq suggested localStorage so upped his answer.